# limit of sequence involving the fractional part

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fractional-part

Using the pigeonhole principle, any sequence of the form $(\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$ where $r$ is an irrational number is dense in the unit interval. Then prove that the following limit does not exit in $[0;\infty]$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\bigg\{\frac{n}{r}\bigg\}$$

Comment: Your thoughts on this problem, how far your got, would be appreciated.

Comment: As the sequence $(\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$ is dense in the unit interval so we can get infinite sub-sequences of $(n\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$ that blow to $\infty$ yet the question is what gonna happen if one chooses a subsequence of $(\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$ that converges to $0$, in such a case the speed of convergence of subsequence of $(\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$ will affect the limit associated of subsequence of $(n\{\frac{n}{r}\})_{n\geq1}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with continued fractions?